# XSL: Getting XML Object from VBS Script

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, vbscript

I've been struggling with following problem: 
- I'd like to pass XML from C# to VBS script embedded in XSL File (done - I sent it as string), 
- Pass this XML to XSL tag `<xsl:for-each>` 
- Iterate over all sub-elements of this XML

c#:

```
namespace EcodMappingUtils
{

[ComVisible(true)]
[Transaction(TransactionOption.RequiresNew)]
[assembly: ApplicationName("EcodMappingUtilsProxy")]
[assembly: ApplicationActivation(ActivationOption.Library)]
public class Proxy : ServicedComponent
{

public object CatalogGet(string p_SrcAliasValue, string p_DestAliasValue, string p_BusinessType_Type)
    {
        return "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><root><b1><content>abc</content></b1> <b2><content>def</content></b2></root>";
    }
}

}
```

vbs in xsl:

```
<msxsl:script language="VBScript" implements-prefix="user">
Function CatalogGet(p_SrcAliasValue, p_DestAliasValue, p_BusinessType_Type)
  Dim obj
  obj = CreateObject("EcodMappingUtils.Proxy")
  CatalogGet = obj.CatalogGet(p_SrcAliasValue, p_DestAliasValue, p_BusinessType_Type)
  End Function
</msxml:script>
```

And when I try to iterate over this XML:

```
<xsl:for-each select="user:CatalogGet('', '', '')">
</xsl:for-each>
```

I got an error, that the expression must return a set of nodes.
I tried to convert string to XMLDOM.Document in VBS, but then I got error during converting from COM Object to CLR.

What should I do?

EDIT:

XSL Transforming:

```
        var myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform(true);

        XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
        settings.EnableScript = true;
        settings.EnableDocumentFunction = true;

        myXslTrans.Load(@"../../test.xslt", settings, new XmlUrlResolver());
        myXslTrans.Transform("../../file.xml", "../../file_out.xml");
```

Comment: Can you clarify which XSLT processor you use, is that .NET's `XslCompiledTransform` or `XslTransform` or is it a version of MSXML, like MSXML 3 or 6?

Comment: I've added clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the XSLT processor is .NET's `XslCompiledTransform` then your "script" is not VBScript but rather VB.NET compiled on the fly to .NET code. And the datatype you need to return is an `XPathNavigator` so for instance

```
  Dim doc As XPathDocument
  Using sr As New StringReader("<root><b1><content>abc</content></b1> <b2><content>def</content></b2></root>")
    doc = New XPathDocument(sr);
  End Using
  Return doc.CreateNavigator()
```

would parse the string as XML, create an XPathDocument and return an XPathNavigator selecting the root node to XSLT/XPath. Your XSLT could then use e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="user:CatalogGet('', '', '')//content">...</xsl:for-each>`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for details on the type mapping between XSLT and .NET.